# Who were the exponents of what Marx dismissed as 'German socialism'?

Tags: communism

In the following passage from *the Communist Manifesto*, Marx takes aim at some of his socialist rivals. He criticises 'feudal' and 'petty bourgeois' socialism... I think I understand what he is criticising there. But who are these 'German, or "True" socialists" he is attacking? What were their names? Sorry about the long quote, but as I didn't really understand it I wasn't sure what part to remove.

> German, or "True," Socialism
>
> The Socialist and Communist literature of France, a literature that
>   originated under the pressure of a bourgeoisie in power, and that was
>   the expression of the struggle against this power, was introduced into
>   Germany at a time when the bourgeoisie, in that country, had just
>   begun its contest with feudal absolutism.
>
> ...
>
> It is well known how the monks wrote silly lives of Catholic Saints
>   over the manuscripts on which the classical works of ancient
>   heathendom had been written. The German literati reversed this process
>   with the profane French literature. They wrote their philosophical
>   nonsense beneath the French original. For instance, beneath the French
>   criticism of the economic functions of money, they wrote "Alienation
>   of Humanity," and beneath the French criticism of the bourgeois State
>   they wrote "dethronement of the Category of the General," and so
>   forth.
>
> ...
>
> The French Socialist and Communist literature was thus completely
>   emasculated. And, since it ceased in the hands of the German to
>   express the struggle of one class with the other, he felt conscious of
>   having overcome "French one-sidedness" and of representing, not true
>   requirements, but the requirements of truth; not the interests of the
>   proletariat, but the interests of Human Nature, of Man in general, who
>   belongs to no class, has no reality, who exists only in the misty
>   realm of philosophical fantasy.
>
> This German Socialism, which took its schoolboy task so seriously and
>   solemnly, and extolled its poor stock-in-trade in such mountebank
>   fashion, meanwhile gradually lost its pedantic innocence.
>
> The fight of the German, and especially, of the Prussian bourgeoisie,
>   against feudal aristocracy and absolute monarchy, in other words, the
>   liberal movement, became more earnest.
>
> By this, the long wished-for opportunity was offered to "True"
>   Socialism of confronting the political movement with the Socialist
>   demands, of hurling the traditional anathemas against liberalism,
>   against representative government, against bourgeois competition,
>   bourgeois freedom of the press, bourgeois legislation, bourgeois
>   liberty and equality, and of preaching to the masses that they had
>   nothing to gain, and everything to lose, by this bourgeois movement.
>   German Socialism forgot, in the nick of time, that the French
>   criticism, whose silly echo it was, presupposed the existence of
>   modern bourgeois society, with its corresponding economic conditions
>   of existence, and the political constitution adapted thereto, the very
>   things whose attainment was the object of the pending struggle in
>   Germany.
>
> To the absolute governments, with their following of parsons,
>   professors, country squires and officials, it served as a welcome
>   scarecrow against the threatening bourgeoisie.
>
> It was a sweet finish after the bitter pills of floggings and bullets
>   with which these same governments, just at that time, dosed the German
>   working-class risings.
>
> While this "True" Socialism thus served the governments as a weapon
>   for fighting the German bourgeoisie, it, at the same time, directly
>   represented a reactionary interest, the interest of the German
>   Philistines. In Germany the petty-bourgeois class, a relic of the
>   sixteenth century, and since then constantly cropping up again under
>   various forms, is the real social basis of the existing state of
>   things.
>
> To preserve this class is to preserve the existing state of things in
>   Germany. The industrial and political supremacy of the bourgeoisie
>   threatens it with certain destruction; on the one hand, from the
>   concentration of capital; on the other, from the rise of a
>   revolutionary proletariat. "True" Socialism appeared to kill these two
>   birds with one stone. It spread like an epidemic.
>
> The robe of speculative cobwebs, embroidered with flowers of rhetoric,
>   steeped in the dew of sickly sentiment, this transcendental robe in
>   which the German Socialists wrapped their sorry "eternal truths," all
>   skin and bone, served to wonderfully increase the sale of their goods
>   amongst such a public. And on its part, German Socialism recognised,
>   more and more, its own calling as the bombastic representative of the
>   petty-bourgeois Philistine.
>
> It proclaimed the German nation to be the model nation, and the German
>   petty Philistine to be the typical man. To every villainous meanness
>   of this model man it gave a hidden, higher, Socialistic
>   interpretation, the exact contrary of its real character. It went to
>   the extreme length of directly opposing the "brutally destructive"
>   tendency of Communism, and of proclaiming its supreme and impartial
>   contempt of all class struggles. With very few exceptions, all the
>   so-called Socialist and Communist publications that now (1847)
>   circulate in Germany belong to the domain of this foul and enervating
>   literature.

Comment: Barbara Tuchman's "The Proud Tower"  contains an excellent and very readable discussion of the evolution of, and relationships between the various branches of socialism, trade unionism, the anarchists, etc. Very much worth a read if this subject is at all of interest to you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Karl Grün](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Gr%C3%BCn) and [Moses Hess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Hess).**

Engels appended a footnote to that section in 1890. It reads:

> The revolutionary storm of 1848 swept away this whole shabby tendency
>   and cured its protagonists of the desire to dabble further in
>   Socialism. The chief representative and classical type of this
>   tendency is Herr Karl Grün.

Wikipedia says that [Karl Grün](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Gr%C3%BCn) was "associated with the group of 'True Socialists' around [Moses Hess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Hess), a Young Hegelian philosopher and forerunner of labour Zionism."

So look for people associated with those two, and those are your "True Socialists."